# When is DryIoc's IfAlreadyRegistered.Keep setting evaluated?

Tags: c#, dryioc

Using DryIoc, if I have a service, `IService`, and two implementations, `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, registered in that order (`ServiceA` then `ServiceB`) with `Reuse.Singleton` lifetime (don't know if that matters or not, but not sure why it would), and `ServiceA` is registered with the setting `IfAlreadyRegistered.Keep`, when a type `IService` is later resolved (by constructor injection of some other class), should I expect to get an instance of `ServiceA`, or `ServiceB`?

The reason I ask the question is because I want to provide a default implementation for `IService` in a shared library (`ServiceA`), but if another party registers an implementation (`ServiceB`), then I want to favor that one. I think I can achieve this with the `IfAlreadyRegistered.Keep` option for `ServiceA`, but the notion of "keeping" an implementation strongly suggests a dependency on the order of registration. In other words, if `ServiceA` is registered first, then no other implementations for `IService` would exist at that point, so I would expect that `IfAlreadyRegistered.Keep` would just register itself in the same way as if `IfAlreadyRegistered` were not explicitly set at all.

To my surprise, I found that regardless of the order of registration, (A then B, or B then A), `ServiceA` was resolved both times. This suggests that perhaps the notion of "keeping" a registration is deferred and evaluated not at the point of registration, and perhaps at the point of resolution.

By contrast however, if I register both implementations with `IfAlreadyRegistered.Throw` (instead of `IfAlreadyRegistered.Keep`), then whichever implementation is registered last immediately throws an exception at the point of registration. I highlight this because it appears that it behaves differently than the `IfAlreadyRegistered.Keep` setting in terms of the point when the `IfAlreadyRegistered` setting is evaluated.

To reiterate, my main question is in the first paragraph. If however there is a better technique for achieving my goal outlined in the first sentence of my second paragraph, then please do share!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace` for the second implementation. That way it will "override" the previous registration, see https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#registerplaceholder and https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/4697be13aceb1ce985a2f3481f233a27c4c69e0b/src/DryIoc/Container.cs#L14828:

> ```
> public enum IfAlreadyRegistered : byte
> {
>     [...]
>     
>     /// <summary>Replaces old registration with new one.</summary>
>     Replace,
>     
>     [...]
> }
> ```

Check the following example code:

```
public interface IService;

public class ServiceA : IService;

public class ServiceB : IService;

public class Program
{       
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        
        container.Register<IService, ServiceA>();
        var service = container.Resolve<IService>();
        Console.WriteLine(service);

        container.Register<IService, ServiceB>(ifAlreadyRegistered: IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace);
        var service2 = container.Resolve<IService>();
        Console.WriteLine(service2);
    }
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
ServiceA
ServiceB
```